# Using variable names rather than ints in a Django url path

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

I have a model called Label:

```
class Label(models.Model):
"""The label a song was released on."""
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the model object."""
    return self.name
```

And I am defining the url path(s) for each individual model instance of label:

```
# Page for a single label.
path('labels/<int:label_id>/', views.label, name='label'),
```

Is it possible to use the label.name attribute rather than an int:label_id in the URL path?  How can this be done?

This is the corresponding code in views.py:

```
def label(request, label_id):
"""Show a single label and associated songs."""
label = Label.objects.get(id=label_id)
context = {'label': label}

return render(request, 'great_songs_app/label.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the name of your incoming parameter and the url:

```
# Page for a single label.
path('labels/<str:name>/', views.label, name='label'),

def label(request, name):
    try:
       label = Label.objects.get(name=name)
    except Label.MultipleObjectsReturned:
       label = None # TODO have a strategy
```

Note that since you are keying off a non-unique parameter, then you could have collisions. Also, you have a very open-ended CharField, which could include spaces, slashes, etc. Better would be to have an explicit "SlugField" to generate this slug:

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

You can then set this SlugField to prepopulate in your admin file ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields)):

```
class LabelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}
```

Finally, I would strongly consider using a DetailView for this, where you get a lot of pre-canned functionality for "free":

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
class LabelDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Label.objects.all()
    slug_field = 'slug' # Or Name, Or Id
    slug_url_kwargs = 'slug' # Or name or label_id
```

Read more about the [Class Based Detail View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

Comment: Instead of handling `MultipleObjectsReturned`, it would be simpler to add `unique=True` to the name field/slug field. As long as you use `<slug:slug>` in your `path()`, you don't need `slug_field` or `slug_url_kwargs` in the detail view.

Answer (score 0):

It's literally the same, you just switch `int` for `str` (= string) and `id` for `name`:

urls:

```
path('labels/<str:label_name>/', views.label, name='label')
```

view:

```
def label(request, label_name):
    l = Label.objects.get(name=label_name)
    …
```

It would be sensible to add `unique=True` to prevent collisions.

If you plan to have names with spaces or other *non-url-friendly* characters, you might want to use [slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) for URL parts instead:

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # create slug from name when saving for the first time
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Label, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

path('labels/<slug:label_slug>/', views.label, name='label')

def label(request, label_slug):
    l = Label.objects.get(slug=label_slug)
    …
```

It's also convenient to use the slug as a primary key.

Comment: Thank you.  I realize this was a basic question but I'm new to this, so I appreciate your help.